# Error installing ipkg on Synology NAS DS414

Tags: linux, nas, synology, ipkg

I have been trying to install ipkg on a Synology NAS according to the instructions available at https://github.com/basmussen/ds414-boostrap-dsm5

Here's the beginning part of the instructions:

```
wget http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/stable/syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
chmod 700 syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
sh syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh
```

However, once I run the syno-mvkw-bootstrap_1.2-7_arm.xsh, I get

`Error: CPU not Marvell Kirkwood, probably wrong bootstrap.xsh`

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

My NAS's info is as below:

**Model name:** DS414

**CPU:** MARVELL Armada XP MV78230

**DSM version:** DSM 6.1.5-15254

I am aware that there is no xsh bootstrap for the ds414 but hopefully, there's a workaround.

Comment: What youŕe trying to install is not for your hardware, the error message is explicit about that. There's no workaround.

Comment: Did you end up installing Optware successfully? I've been struggling to get some unpackaged software running on my DS216j running DSM 6.2.1-23824 Update 1, and there seems to be a lot of outdated information on the web. I've yet to find any information confirming that it is actually possible to set up an alternative package manager on low-end Synology NASes running a current version of the DSM.

Comment: @sjy I ended up manually installing Easy Bootstrap Installer via the package center with the package source https://www.cphub.net, the package can be downloaded at https://www.cphub.net/?p=ebi.